# how to mail dynamically generated dropdown fields values in PHP?

Tags: javascript, forms, dropdown

I am trying to mail two dynmically generated fields values.

My mark up is:

```
<div class="multi-field-wrapper">
  <button type="button" class="add-field">Add Destination</button>        
  <div class="multi-fields">
    <div class="multi-field">
      <select class="text-one" name="destination[]">
            <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
            <option value="colombo">Colombo</option>
            <option value="kandy">Kandy</option>
            <option value="anuradhapura">Anuradhapura</option>
        </select>

        <br />

        <select class="text-two" name="attraction[]">
            <option>Please choose from above</option>
        </select>
      <!--a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="INQUIRE" value="INQUIRE"/>
```

so when the button "Add Destination" is clicked a set of drop down buttons are generated using following `JavaScript`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.multi-field-wrapper').each(function() {
        var $wrapper = $('.multi-fields', this);
        var x = 1;
        $(".add-field", $(this)).click(function(e) {
            x++;
                $($wrapper).append('<div class="multi-field"><select class="text-one'+x+'" name="destination[]"><option selected value="base">Please Select</option><option value="colombo">Colombo</option><option value="kandy">Kandy</option><option value="anuradhapura">Anuradhapura</option></select><br /><select class="text-two'+x+'" name="attraction[]"><option>Please choose from above</option></select><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
        //alert(x);
        //alert (".text-one"+x);

            $(function() {      
                $(".text-one").change(function() {
                    $(".text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
                });
            });

            $(function() {      
                $(".text-one"+x).change(function() {
                    $(".text-two"+x).load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
                });
            });
        });

        $($wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
            e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
        })
    });
});
```

And that works fine here : http://goo.gl/V8N91a

and now I want to get those field values and mail to my email.
What I mean is I have to get "attraction" s according to it's "Destination" s.

I know I can get dynamically generated field values by doing somethig like below:

```
foreach($_POST['destination'] as $value) {
 print $value.'<br/><br/>';
}
```

it will just list the values.
But how can I get attraction and destination together and mail using:

```
if (isset($_POST['INQUIRE']))  { 
    $msg = 'Here I have to get the attractions and destinations';
    mail("myemail@gmail.com","Custom Tour Package",$msg);
}
```

What I have to do to get the mail as I explained above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
if(isset($_POST['INQUIRE'])) {
    $msg = '';
    foreach($_POST['destination'] as $key => $val) {
        $msg .= ' Destination : ' . $val . ', Attraction : ' . $_POST['attraction'][$key] . '<br />';
    }
    mail("myemail@gmail.com", "Custom Tour Package", $msg);
}
```

Comment: @mastarted could you have a look at this question too please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34916688/how-to-get-a-set-of-dropdown-list-values-and-email-it-using-php